# Calling the default constructor in scala

Tags: scala

I have a class definition in scala

```
class A(p1: Type1,p2: Type2){
    def this(p1: Type1){  //my constructor
       this()
       this.p1 = somevalue
    }
}
```

what is the difference between

```
1. val a:A = new A //Is this same as A()??
2. val a:A = new A(v1,v2)
```

How come 1. gives a compile time error? but calling this() inside "my constructor" doesn't give an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you have provided does not compile. `this()` is not valid because there is no default constructor for the class `A`. `this.p1 = somevalue` is wrong, because there is not member `p1`.

Correctly it might look like this:

```
 class A(p1: Type1, p2: Type2) {
    def this(p1: Type1) {
      this(p1, someValueForP2)
    }
 }
```

or even better with default values:

```
class A(p1: Type1 = defaultForP1, p2: Type2 = defaultForP2)
```

Comment: my bad i didn't actually compile the code, my idea intellij ide didn't point out the error